# Tooltip not displayed on selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to display a value on mouse-hover of `<p:selectOneMenu>`. I specified the attribute 'title'. However, tool-tip does not get displayed.

Please note I do not need tooltip on selectItem. But, on selectOneMenu.

I tried analyzing primefaces' code. `SelectOneMenu extends HtmlSelectOneMenu`. `HtmlSelectOneMenu` does have getters & setters for 'title' attribute.

Primefaces version : 4.0

Comment: I don't have any title attribute for `<p:selectOneMenu>` with Primefaces 5.0. You better add a `<p:tooltip>` for your select menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the p:tooltip to place a tooltip on any of your components.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="sel1menu" ...>
                    ...
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:tooltip for="sel1menu">Select this</p:tooltip>
```